# How to test that a JavaScript object has only specific fields/properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function which tests that an object has certain fields

```
validateServerResponseStructure(res: any) {
    let isTypeCorrect: boolean = (
      res.result != undefined) && (res['additional-info'] != undefined
    );
    return isTypeCorrect;
  }
```

Is there a way to test that `res` has only `result` and `additional-info` properties and nothing else?

Comment: You should have used `in` operator instead: eg: `'result' in res`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that the length of its `keys` is exactly two. Also, probably best to use strict equality comparison, if you want to ensure that the properties are not `undefined`:

```
validateServerResponseStructure(res: any) {
  let isTypeCorrect: boolean = (
    res.result !== undefined
    && res['additional-info'] !== undefined
    && Object.keys(res).length === 2
  );
  return isTypeCorrect;
}
```

In the unusual case that you may have properties that contain the `undefined` value, and you want to permit such values, check the length of the keys, and that both `result` and `additional-info` are included in the keys:

```
const keys = Object.keys(res);
let isTypeCorrect: boolean = (
  ['result', 'additional-info'].every(key => keys.includes(key))
  && keys.length === 2
)
```

Comment: You say " best to use strict equality", but you don't use it. You should use `typeof res.result !== "undefined"
    && typeof res['additional-info'] !== "undefined"`

Comment: `res.result !== undefined` does not check if a property exists, but only if its value is not `undefined`. `{ foo: undefined }` --- here the `.foo` property would exist yet it's `undefined`.

Comment: @TsahiAsher "Strict equality" refers to using `===` and `!==` rather than `==` and `!=`. Pretty sure adding `typeof` only adds a bit of syntax noise

Comment: @zerkms - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ManuChadha you asked "How to test that a JavaScript object has only specific fields/properties
" --- you don't check if an object has a particular property with `!== undefined`. Equality to `undefined` has nothing to do with property presence. To check if property presents you need to use `in` or `Object.keys` as in this answer